# Get HTML5 range value in Ruby on Rails form

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, forms, slider

I am trying to change the standard Ruby on Rails form to let the user input a value with HTML5 range. I can't figure out how I should replace the standard "<%= f.text_field :W1 %>".

I have a slider :

```
<input class="slide" type="range" min="0" max="200" id="slider1">
```

Displaying value in :

```
<text id="W1">100</text>
```

Thanks to Ajax :

```
    $("#slider1").change(function () {                    
   var newValue = $('#slider1').val();
   $("#W1").html(newValue);
});
```

I can't find out where and how I should get the input value to set W1 ?

EDIT : HTML5 range is range_field form herlper in Ruby. I'm still searching for the right implementation of it so any help would be appreciated

Comment: this is really just a javascript question, not so much about ruby.

Comment: The thing is that I'm in a Ruby form, so I want to have the Ruby way to send the W1 value in the _form.html.erb

Comment: In fact, I discovered, that I should use the range_field form helper from Ruby. I'm still fighting with it though :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have it ! I had to replace

```
<input class="slide" type="range" min="0" max="200" id="slider1">
```

by

```
<%= f.range_field :w1, :min=>0, :max=>200, :class=>"slide", :id=>"slider1"%>
```

Thanks to those who helped me !

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#W1").val(newValue);
```

This should do it.

Comment: In the Ajax ? The <%= f.text_field :W1 %> was in the HTML part.